# How can I check the logs for NServiceBus license updates

Tags: nservicebus

I want to know who has updated the NServiceBus license and when it has been done? How can I get this information.

I have NServiceBus version 5, and i have the rolling log files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to get in touch with Particular Software to renew/extend your license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software license and how to obtain it.

Comment: I have valid licenses with me, the only thing I want to check when does the last license updated and who did that. Could you please help with that?

Comment: It depends on the type of your license and the expiration date. If you send an email to support at particular dot net we'll put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i will close this question.